# Saving workspace from an inactive R console

Tags: r

I have been working in a current session in R for a few days now, however the console has become somewhat unresponsive. I cannot get the command prompt to become 'active', though I can click on some of the menus from the menu bar. However, the "save workspace" menu option is unresponsive. Is there a way to access and save the objects I have saved in my current R session? Maybe trying to access the folder R temporarily stores data in???

THanks

Comment: I think the answer is no. R creates a temporary directory when you open a session, but it doesn't store anything there unless you tell it to. (This is my understanding of Windows at least, perhaps another OS behaves differently.)

Comment: You could use `Sys.getenv("TMPDIR")` to find your temporary directory, but not if you can't execute the code I guess.

Comment: THanks Thomas and Scott. I guess I have to start over from scratch